# Selectively ignoring tuples from a table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The problem that we are tackling with a data mining application is best described with an illustrative example.

There is a sample table `myTable`, which is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
  id        INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  colA      VARCHAR(8),
  colB      VARCHAR(12),
  revFlag   CHAR(8), -- 'REVISED' or any other value, including NULL

  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Any tuple with a `revFlag` value of `REVISED` takes precedence over any other tuple with the same value for `colA`, as long as the `revFlag` value of the latter tuple is not `REVISED`.  In other words when we select rows from the table we skip all rows for which the `revFlag` value is not `REVISED` and there exists a row with the same value for `colA` for which the `revFlag` value is `REVISED`.

We populate the table as follows:

```
INSERT INTO myTable(colA, colB) VALUES ('XSR0KA3V', 'OLD-O7RAR81X'),
('4F2JG71O', 'OLD-E71BE63L'), ('MML3HN48', 'OLD-B02PFB63'),
('5H0MWVSB', 'OLD-V70XLGHT'), ('JW73ZX0J', 'OLD-KME1GXQF'),
('XZV0EY0G', 'OLD-N06BURDF'), ('9HBQZ88V', 'OLD-76HSPUAL'),
('YI5AT6G4', 'OLD-X8KAWD7Z');


INSERT INTO myTable(colA, colB, revFlag) VALUES
('XSR0KA3V', 'NEW-O7RAR81X', 'REVISED'),
('MML3HN48', 'NEW-B02PFB63', 'REVISED'),
('9HBQZ88V', 'NEW-76HSPUAL', 'REVISED'),
('YI5AT6G4', 'NEW-X8KAWD7Z', 'XYZ'),
('Z8H2B5KY', '3RINJV0K', 'REVISED');
```

Naturally `SELECT * FROM myTable` yields the following:

```
+----+----------+--------------+---------+
| id | colA     | colB         | revFlag |
+----+----------+--------------+---------+
|  1 | XSR0KA3V | OLD-O7RAR81X | NULL    |
|  2 | 4F2JG71O | OLD-E71BE63L | NULL    |
|  3 | MML3HN48 | OLD-B02PFB63 | NULL    |
|  4 | 5H0MWVSB | OLD-V70XLGHT | NULL    |
|  5 | JW73ZX0J | OLD-KME1GXQF | NULL    |
|  6 | XZV0EY0G | OLD-N06BURDF | NULL    |
|  7 | 9HBQZ88V | OLD-76HSPUAL | NULL    |
|  8 | YI5AT6G4 | OLD-X8KAWD7Z | NULL    |
|  9 | XSR0KA3V | NEW-O7RAR81X | REVISED |
| 10 | MML3HN48 | NEW-B02PFB63 | REVISED |
| 11 | 9HBQZ88V | NEW-76HSPUAL | REVISED |
| 12 | YI5AT6G4 | NEW-X8KAWD7Z | XYZ     |
| 13 | Z8H2B5KY | 3RINJV0K     | REVISED |
+----+----------+--------------+---------+
```

---

We would like to design a query that does **not** return any tuples that are **REVISED** by other tuples.  In our case the output should look like this:

```
+----+----------+--------------+---------+
| id | colA     | colB         | revFlag |
+----+----------+--------------+---------+
|  2 | 4F2JG71O | OLD-E71BE63L | NULL    |
|  4 | 5H0MWVSB | OLD-V70XLGHT | NULL    |
|  5 | JW73ZX0J | OLD-KME1GXQF | NULL    |
|  6 | XZV0EY0G | OLD-N06BURDF | NULL    |
|  8 | YI5AT6G4 | OLD-X8KAWD7Z | NULL    |
|  9 | XSR0KA3V | NEW-O7RAR81X | REVISED |
| 10 | MML3HN48 | NEW-B02PFB63 | REVISED |
| 11 | 9HBQZ88V | NEW-76HSPUAL | REVISED |
| 12 | YI5AT6G4 | NEW-X8KAWD7Z | XYZ     |
| 13 | Z8H2B5KY | 3RINJV0K     | REVISED |
+----+----------+--------------+---------+
```

Comment: I presume when there are two rows with the `revFlag = 'REVISED'` for the same value of `colA`, you'd want to take the row that is newer of the two?

Comment: @J.D. Although we have not seen a situation yet where there are multiple rows with the `revFlag = 'REVISED'` for the same value of `colA`, in such a situation we would go with the **newest** row (i.e. with the highest value of `id`)

Comment: Please see my additional questions in the comments of my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a [**window function**](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-functions/) like the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/row_number/) function inside of a subquery or CTE like so:

```
SELECT id, colA, colB, revFlag
FROM
(
    SELECT id, colA, colB, revFlag, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        (
            PARTITION BY colA 
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN revFlag = 'REVISED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC, id DESC
        ) AS SortOrder -- Generates a unique ID for each row of the same value of colA sorted by revFlag = 'REVISED' first then by id descending
    FROM myTable
) myTableSorted
WHERE SortOrder = 1
```

As per my comment, the `SortOrder` field is generated by partitioning on `colA` and within that partition generating a unique incremental id that is sorted with the `revFlag = 'REVISED'` having priority first, and then by the `myTable.id` column descending (to get the latest row per `colA`).

Comment: The query does not return *{8, YI5AT6G4, OLD-X8KAWD7Z, NULL}*

Comment: @Sandeep Ah I did not notice that in your sample data. So in cases where the `revFlag` does not equal `REVISED` you want to return all rows with dupes of `colA`? What about the case where there is a row with `revFlag = 'REVISED'` and for the same `colA` value there's a newer row that came after where `revFlag` doesn't equal `REVISED`, would you expect both rows back or just the older `REVISED` row?